# How to change the color of a specific part of an SVG using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, svg, tailwind-css

How can I change the color of only the wrist separator in the ThumbsUp SVG icon to black and fill the rest of the parts with white? It would be great if at least there is a clear distinction between the wrist and the rest of the parts, giving the user a sense of differentiation.

[image]

The desired final appearance I want is as follows.

[image]

The following code fills all areas with white color.

```js
import { ThumbsUp } from "lucide-react";

<ThumbsUp
  strokeWidth={1}
  size={20}
  className={`${
    commentReaction?.type === "LIKE"
      ? "stroke-black [&>*:nth-child(2)]:fill-base-white"
      : "dark:text-base-white"
  }`}
/>
```

From what I understand, the first path is the wrist separator, and the second path represents the rest of the area. In my opinion, it seems like either the `:nth-child` pseudo-class is being used incorrectly or it may not be necessary. I'm not sure, but is there anyone who might know a solution?

```html
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  width="24"
  height="24"
  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
  fill="none"
  stroke="currentColor"
  stroke-width="1"
  stroke-linecap="round"
  stroke-linejoin="round"
  className="lucide lucide-thumbs-up"
  >
  <path d="M7 10v12" />  {/* The wrist sepeartor */}
  <path d="M15 5.88 14 10h5.83a2 2 0 0 1 1.92 2.56l-2.33 8A2 2 0 0 1 17.5 22H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h2.76a2 2 0 0 0 1.79-1.11L12 2h0a3.13 3.13 0 0 1 3 3.88Z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the second path is a border around the `ThumbsUp`, so if you use `fill` it'll fill all the area with the color you want but that covers the wrist too.
On the other hand, if you use `stroke`, it only changes the color of the border and will not fill it with your color.
So IMO, the better option is to use a different `SVG` for this approach:

```html
<svg class="w-24 h-24" fill="green" viewBox="0 0 8 8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"> <path d="M4.47 0c-.19.02-.37.15-.47.34-.13.26-1.09 2.19-1.28 2.38-.19.19-.44.28-.72.28v4h3.5c.21 0 .39-.13.47-.31 0 0 1.03-2.91 1.03-3.19 0-.28-.22-.5-.5-.5h-1.5c-.28 0-.5-.25-.5-.5s.39-1.58.47-1.84c.08-.26-.05-.54-.31-.63-.07-.02-.12-.04-.19-.03zm-4.47 3v4h1v-4h-1z"></path> </g></svg>




<svg class="w-24 h-24" fill="#000000" viewBox="0 0 8 8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)rotate(180)"><g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"> <path d="M4.47 0c-.19.02-.37.15-.47.34-.13.26-1.09 2.19-1.28 2.38-.19.19-.44.28-.72.28v4h3.5c.21 0 .39-.13.47-.31 0 0 1.03-2.91 1.03-3.19 0-.28-.22-.5-.5-.5h-1.5c-.28 0-.5-.25-.5-.5s.39-1.58.47-1.84c.08-.26-.05-.54-.31-.63-.07-.02-.12-.04-.19-.03zm-4.47 3v4h1v-4h-1z"></path> </g></svg>



<svg fill='blue' version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 122.88 106.16" style="enable-background:new 0 0 122.88 106.16" xml:space="preserve"><style type="text/css">.st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;}</style><g><path class="st0" d="M4.02,44.6h27.36c2.21,0,4.02,1.81,4.02,4.03v53.51c0,2.21-1.81,4.03-4.02,4.03H4.02 c-2.21,0-4.02-1.81-4.02-4.03V48.63C0,46.41,1.81,44.6,4.02,44.6L4.02,44.6z M63.06,4.46c2.12-10.75,19.72-0.85,20.88,16.48 c0.35,5.3-0.2,11.47-1.5,18.36l25.15,0c10.46,0.41,19.59,7.9,13.14,20.2c1.47,5.36,1.69,11.65-2.3,14.13 c0.5,8.46-1.84,13.7-6.22,17.84c-0.29,4.23-1.19,7.99-3.23,10.88c-3.38,4.77-6.12,3.63-11.44,3.63H55.07 c-6.73,0-10.4-1.85-14.8-7.37V51.31c12.66-3.42,19.39-20.74,22.79-32.11V4.46L63.06,4.46z"/></g></svg>




<svg fill='green' version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 122.88 106.16" style="enable-background:new 0 0 122.88 106.16" xml:space="preserve"><style type="text/css">.st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;}</style><g><path class="st0" d="M4.03,61.56h27.36c2.21,0,4.02-1.81,4.02-4.02V4.03C35.41,1.81,33.6,0,31.39,0H4.03C1.81,0,0,1.81,0,4.03 v53.51C0,59.75,1.81,61.56,4.03,61.56L4.03,61.56z M63.06,101.7c2.12,10.75,19.72,0.85,20.88-16.48c0.35-5.3-0.2-11.47-1.5-18.36 l25.15,0c10.46-0.41,19.59-7.9,13.14-20.2c1.47-5.36,1.69-11.65-2.3-14.13c0.5-8.46-1.84-13.7-6.22-17.84 c-0.29-4.23-1.19-7.99-3.23-10.88c-3.38-4.77-6.12-3.63-11.44-3.63H55.07c-6.73,0-10.4,1.85-14.8,7.37v47.31 c12.66,3.42,19.39,20.74,22.79,32.11V101.7L63.06,101.7L63.06,101.7z"/></g></svg>
```

Comment: Could you please add a thumbs down svg in your answer as well? If there are no better alternatives, I will use the new SVG as you suggested.

Comment: One more thing to add: How can I use it as an icon without filled colors? If I use stroke="white", it makes the wrist thicker, and it doesn't look right with filled colors. I need to use an additional SVG, which is not an ideal solution for me.

Comment: I added the thumb down too. You could easily search for thumb `SVG` icons on the internet and modify them as you wish. I found these on the first try.

Comment: I also added two more `SVG`s with thinner wrists

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, it seems that there is an issue with your response when the icon is not filled with color. When the user has not clicked the icon, I would like to see an empty icon, and when they click it, I want the icon to be filled with color except for the wrist part. To adopt your response, it seems that I would need to use two thumbs up SVGs. Is it possible to have one SVG that allows for selecting the color?

Comment: Yes, I think the same and you need to use two different `SVG`s.

Comment: I will wait for a few days to see if there is a response suggesting a solution that can resolve the issue using only one SVG. If there is no other way, I will adopt your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ThumbsUp className="[&>*:first-child]:stroke-black" />
```

Comment: It didn't work.